# Split paths and hashes into 2 different variables

Tags: javascript

I have one variable. The variable looks like this:

```
path1/path2,hash
path1/path2,hash
path1/path2,hash
path1/path2,hash
```

etc, etc.

How do I get 2 different variables, one containing the paths and the other containing the hashes?

For example, the paths will be like this:

```
path/path
path/path
path/path
path/path
```

I'm new to javascript btw, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean *'the variable looks like this'*? Is it a single multi-line string?

Comment: yes, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: And you want to split paths and hashes into two single multi-line strings?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to split all the content into two multi line string, then this peace of code could help to you.

```
let arrOfPathAndHash = `path1/path2,hash
path1/path2,hash
path1/path2,hash
path1/path2,hash`.split('\n');

arrOfPathAndHash = arrOfPathAndHash.map((pathAndHash) => pathAndHash.split(','));

const paths = arrOfPathAndHash.map((pathAndHash) => pathAndHash[0]).join('\n');
// path1/path2
// path1/path2
// path1/path2
// path1/path2

const hashes = arrOfPathAndHash.map((pathAndHash) => pathAndHash[1]).join('\n');
// hash
// hash
// hash
// hash
```